Binding data from database to a dropdownlist in Angular 17 and .NetCore 8 not working
I am trying to bind data fetched from database to a dropdownlist upon loading a certain component/page in a nG17 app. The backend API is written in .NetCore 8. I have done the relevant pieces of code in the backend and the frontend. I had hoped that it would work just fine but no. I am getting an empty dropdown. Nothing is being populated. Let me share the related pieces of code so that you can see what I did.
Category.cs
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CatgoryName { get; set; }
}

WebAPI endpoint
[HttpGet]
[Route("jobcategories")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetAllJobCategories()
{
    var jobcategories = await _dbContext.Categories.ToListAsync();
    if(jobcategories.Count>0)
    {
        return Ok(jobcategories);
    }
    else
    {
        return NotFound(new
        {
            Message = "No job categories found!"
        }); 
    }
    
}

base.service.ts
getAllJobCategories():Observable<any>
  {
    return this.http.get(environment.baseEndPoint+'/jobcategories');
  }

category.model.ts
export interface Category{
    id:number;
    categoryName:string;
}

post-job.component.ts
jobCategories:Category[]=[];

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.baseService.getAllJobCategories()
        .subscribe({
          next:(res:any)=>
          {
            if(res!=null)
            {
              this.jobCategories=res;
              console.log(this.jobCategories);
            }
            else
            {
              console.log('problem fetching job categories');
            }
          },
          error:err=>
          {
            console.log('Server Error:/n', err.error.message);
          }
        })
    
  }

The response I am getting in console is like Array(15) which when expanded shows that the data is there.
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "catgoryName": "Web Developer"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "catgoryName": "Fullstack Developer"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "catgoryName": "Frontend Developer"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "catgoryName": "DSA Professional"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "catgoryName": "AI and ML Professional"
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "catgoryName": "Technical Content Writer Professional"
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "catgoryName": "DBA Professional"
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "catgoryName": "Mobile Application Developer"
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "catgoryName": "Systems Networking Professional"
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "catgoryName": "HR Professional"
    },
    {
        "id": 11,
        "catgoryName": "Backend Developer"
    },
    {
        "id": 12,
        "catgoryName": "Project Manager"
    },
    {
        "id": 13,
        "catgoryName": "Delivery Manager"
    },
    {
        "id": 14,
        "catgoryName": "Process Manager"
    },
    {
        "id": 15,
        "catgoryName": "Module Leader"
    }
]

post-job.component.html
<div class="mb-3">
            <select formControlName="category" class="form-select" id="categoryDropDown" (change)="changeCategory($event)">
                <option *ngFor="let jobcategory of jobCategories;" [value]="jobcategory.id">
                    {{jobcategory.categoryName}}
                </option>
             </select>
        </div>

I double checked to see if the API endpoint is being hit and if data is really being fetched. No problem there. I consoled the response. I am getting the data from the database in the form of an array. The data is there.
So what's wrong? Where am I committing the mistake? The binding in the html element, or the data format? Why am I getting a blank dropdown? Can you folks spot the problem in code or logic? Please suggest what to rectify.
***** I forgot to mention one thing. My dropdown is inside a reactive form. So the code where I used formBuilder to initialize my form was originally like
newJobForm=this.formBuilder.group({
    title:['', Validators.required],
    description:['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength]],
    category:['', Validators.required],
    applyUrl:['', Validators.required],
  })

You can see category is initialized like
category:['', Validators.required]

Could that have anything to do?

Have you confirmed that your jobCategories contains the data that you expect?

hi @Peppermintology  I consoled the jobCategories to check it. It contains the data in the form of Array(15). Please check my updated question to see the nature of response.

@Peppermintology I forgot to mention one thing earlier. My dropdown is inside a reactive form. Pl refer the above posted question's bottom part.

In the data you posted you misspelled the "CategoryName" attribute in your Category class:
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CatgoryName { get; set; }
}

You can see in the response you wrote to console that your angular object has the same misspelling:
{
    "id": 15,
    "catgoryName": "Module Leader"
}

But your binding in the html has the correct spelling:
{{jobcategory.categoryName}}


Hi @Kevin Thanks for replying! What a shame! I have been running up and down my code and scouring through the internet wondering what could be wrong! And in the end it was this bit of misspelled property 'catgoryName'!! It's working OK now. WHAT A SHAME !! Much Ado About Nothing !!!
